# QGraphicsItems that are related through a parent QGraphicsItem have wrong transforms after rotating them

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem, qt4.8

I have QGraphicsItems of different shapes, which the user can create.
Each one is composed of:

- a parent QGraphicsItem holding everything together
- a translationhandle (a QGraphicsItem itself) for user interactions: translations
- a rotationhandle (a QGraphicsItem itself) for user interactions: rotations
- 1 or more point handles (a QGraphicsItem itself) representing the shape
- 1 QPainterPath, which is always drawn in-between the point handles.

Moving the Point Handles results in changing only a part of the shape, moving the rotation or translation handle, results in rotating and translating the whole item.

Everything works quite well, except the one situation: moving the point handles when the whole setup is rotated. Then the other point handles are getting moved also and the translations arent fitting to the mouse movement. If the whole setup is unrotated (rotation = 0.0), everything works well. Also when rotating the setup back to 0.0.

I tried almost any change, with setTransformOriginPoint and without. Anyone had this behaviour in the past and a idea?

Thanks a lot
Stefan

Code Example as requested:

Creation of the "mother" item:

```
    BaseItem::BaseItem() : 
    QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem(),
    ...
{
    setFlags( ItemIsSelectable );

    m_rotateHandle = new RotationHandle(this);
    m_translateHandle = new TranslationHandle(this);

    ...
}
```

Creation of the Translation Handle: (parent is the item above)

```
BaseItem::TranslationHandle::TranslationHandle( BaseItem* parent ) : 
    QGraphicsRectItem(-6, -6, 12, 12, parent), 
    m_parent(parent)
{
    setFlag( ItemIsMovable);
    setFlag( ItemIgnoresTransformations);
    setPos(100, 100);
}
```

Creation of the Rotation Handle: (parent is the item above)

```
    BaseItem::RotationHandle::RotationHandle( BaseItem* parent) : 
    QGraphicsEllipseItem(-6, -6, 12, 12, parent), 
    m_parent(parent),
    m_angle(0.0f)
{
    setFlag( ItemIsMovable );
    setFlag( ItemIgnoresTransformations);
    setPos(150, 150);
}
```

Rotation Event Handler:

```
void BaseItem::RotationHandle::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{ 
    m_angle += (event->scenePos() - event->lastScenePos()).x();
    QList<QGraphicsItem*> items = m_parent->scene()->selectedItems();
    foreach(QGraphicsItem* item, items) {
        BaseItem* bs_item = dynamic_cast<BaseShapeItem*>(item);
        if(bs_item) {
            bs_item->setRotation(m_angle);
        }
    }
}
```

The point handle constructor:

```
    BaseItem::PointHandle::PointHandle( QPointF position, BaseItem* parent, QColor penColor) : 
    QGraphicsRectItem(-4, -4, 8, 8, parent), 
    m_parent(parent)
{
    setPos(position);
    setFlag( ItemIsMovable );
    setFlag( ItemIgnoresTransformations);
}
```

the move event for the point handle:

```
void BaseItem::PointHandle::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{ 
    this->setPos( mapToParent(event->pos()) );
    m_parent->updateShape();
}
```

the update shape method:

```
void BaseItem::updateShape()
{
    QPointF center = m_shape.boundingRect().center();
    setTransformOriginPoint( center );
    m_rotateHandle->setPos( center );
    m_translateHandle->setPos(center.x(), center.y()-20);
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the code of how you setup the QGraphicsItem with its translation handle and rotation handle and how you perform the rotation, it's very difficult to guess what's causing the problem here. I suspect it may be an issue of the wrong coordinate space. Can you provide code examples?

Comment: I added some examples, i hope they are helpful, code is extensive, so just posting everything would be too much.

Comment: If your base class inherits from QGraphicsItem, rather than QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem and implement boundingRect() and shape(), you can then use the paint() function to draw useful debug info. Initially, I think the problem lies in the transform origin point not being where you think it is. Have you drawn it to see if it's doing what you expect?